# Which is the better ros distro for ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros, ros-electric, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Which is the better ros distro (groovy/electric/fuerte) for ubuntu 11.10 for a biginner?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57214/which-is-the-better-ros-distro-for-ubuntu-11.10/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Groovy is the latest release, i would go for that one under Ubuntu 11.10
The reasons are because many tools have been upgraded or updated.

Please note that Groovy is the latest release, Fuerte is the previous one (and my second choice as it is a relatively stable and well-documented version) and electric is the oldest one you mentioned.

For further info consult this link:
[ROS Installation - Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories)

---

Originally posted by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) with karma: 216 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-23**:
+1 If you are just starting a project, it makes sense to use the most recent ROS distro that is supported on your platform, in this case Groovy. Note however, that Hydro will *not* support Ubuntu 11.10. You might want to upgrade to 12.04, Precise, instead.